# For which primes $p$ and positive integers $k$ is the deficiency $D(p^k)$ equal to the arithmetic derivative of $p^k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, diophantine-equations, divisor-sum

**The Problem**

> For which primes $p$ and positive integers $k$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) $D(p^k)$ equal to the [arithmetic derivative](http://oeis.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative#Arithmetic_derivative_of_natural_numbers) of $p^k$?

**My Attempt**

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

The *deficiency* of $x$ is given by the formula
$$D(x)=2x-\sigma(x).$$

So, when $p$ is prime and $k$ is a positive integer, we get
$$D(p^k)=2p^k-\sigma(p^k)=2p^k-\bigg(\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}\bigg)=\frac{p^{k+1} - 2p^k + 1}{p - 1}.$$

But the *arithmetic derivative* of $p^k$ is given by (the usual formula)
$$kp^{k-1}.$$

Equating, we obtain
$$kp^{k-1}=D(p^k)=\frac{p^{k+1} - 2p^k + 1}{p - 1}.$$

Suppose that $k=1$.  Then we get
$$\frac{p^2 - 2p + 1}{p - 1}=\frac{(p-1)^2}{p-1}=p-1=1 \implies p=2.$$

Now, assume that $k>1$.  Then we have
$$kp^k - kp^{k-1}=p^{k+1} - 2p^k + 1$$
from which follows that
$$-p^{k+1} + (k+2)p^k - kp^{k-1} = 1.$$
But since $k>1$ and $p$ is prime, the $\text{LHS}$ of the last equation is divisible by $p^{k-1} > 1$.  This contradicts the fact that $p^{k-1} > 1$ does not divide the $\text{RHS}$.

> Hence, the only solution is
> $$(p,k)=(2,1).$$

**Question**

> Is this solution/proof correct?

Comment: Right method, right answer as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, @JohnOmielan!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, @tkf!

Comment: I invite you to write out an actual answer to the question, so that I may be able to accept it (and so that the question does not remain in the unanswered queue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you've done appears to be correct. In fact, the methods you used are basically the same ones I would have used if I were to answer it.